# Where does the Energy for $W$ and $Z$ Boson Emission come from?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, bosons, electroweak

I understand that the Weak interaction is mediated by the $W$ and $Z$ bosons, and that their huge masses are the reason for the Weak interaction's short range.

However, I cannot find an explanation for why they are created. As they are such massive particles, $\geq$80 times the rest mass of a proton, I assume their creation requires a lot of energy, where does this energy come from?

Comment: Take my comment with a grain of salt since I am no expert in QFT, but it should be allowed by the uncertainty principle as long as it happens in a short time since $\Delta t \Delta E \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ and that's why interactions mediated by heavier particles have a shorter range.

Comment: Even though, as you say, weak interactions are mediated by $W$ and $Z$ bosons, they are not necessarily created on-shell, thus not requiring energies comparable to their mass - e.g. beta-decays are mediated by virtual $W$s for which the square of the four-momentum does not obey $p_\mu^2 = m^2$, while in e.g. top quark decays $t \rightarrow Wb$, the $W$ are on-mass.

Comment: I never really considered this, thank you both for your answers! That's so interesting that particles can form "off mass", do you know of any references where I can learn more about this?

Comment: There are a few questions on this forum related to on-shell and off-shell (virtual) particles, with links to other questions and sources. Try [this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108546/where-does-this-term-shell-with-prefix-on-off-come-from?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the links/sources therein.

Comment: see virtual particles http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html  and my answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90928/virtual-higgs-boson/90973#90973